# How to close xls sheet after running macro automatically

Tags: macros, xls

I have following macro code, this will run macro automatically and login into mentioned website. But xls sheets remains opened ..

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Auto_open()

login

End Sub


Sub login()
Dim IntExpl As Object
Set IntExpl = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Dim dd As Object
Dim dd1 As Object
Dim dd2 As Object
Dim dd3 As Object

With IntExpl
      .navigate "........."
      .Visible = True
     ' If (.Document.getElementById("LoginUsername").exist) Then
       Do Until IntExpl.ReadyState = 4
       Loop
       Set dd = .Document.getElementById("LoginUsername")
       dd.Value = "AAAAA"
       dd.Click
       Set dd1 = .Document.getElementById("LoginPassword")
       dd1.Value = "AAAAAA"
       dd1.Click
       Set dd2 = .Document.getElementById("loginBtn")
       dd2.Click


End With
End Sub
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to close xls file also after running whole macro.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your workbook and then close it once the macro is completed.

```
Sub Auto_open()

Dim wb as Workbook
set wb = ActiveWorkbook
login
wb.close
End Sub


Sub login()
Dim IntExpl As Object
Set IntExpl = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Dim dd As Object
Dim dd1 As Object
Dim dd2 As Object
Dim dd3 As Object

With IntExpl
      .navigate "........."
      .Visible = True
     ' If (.Document.getElementById("LoginUsername").exist) Then
       Do Until IntExpl.ReadyState = 4
       Loop
       Set dd = .Document.getElementById("LoginUsername")
       dd.Value = "AAAAA"
       dd.Click
       Set dd1 = .Document.getElementById("LoginPassword")
       dd1.Value = "AAAAAA"
       dd1.Click
       Set dd2 = .Document.getElementById("loginBtn")
       dd2.Click


End With
End Sub
```

Comment: and also i want to pick the data from xls sheet.

Comment: Set dd = .Document.getElementById("LoginUsername")
       dd.Value = "AAAAA"
the value AAAAA needs to be pick from XLs

Comment: Press F8 on your keyboard and go through the code step by step, let us know in case there is any error. Instead of AAAAA you can use Worksheets("sheetname").Range("A1")

Comment: i m using Worksheets("sheetname").Range("A1") .. My values is 000549 but it is taking it as 549 ... What should i do ????

Comment: Great!!, here on stackoverflow, we mark the question as complete (clicking the right icon below my answer) and grant some reputation to the answeree to keep moral high, would you be kind enough to accept the answer, you can upvote as well.